# VB.Net How to highlight current line only

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a syntax highlighting feature to my text box, but I'm having an issue. After hours of searching, I found a post with exactly what I was looking for. Here is the code that searches for words in a list, and highlights them:

```
        If editorBox.Text.Length > 0 Then
        Dim selectStart As Integer = editorBox.SelectionStart

        editorBox.Select(0, editorBox.Text.Length)

        editorBox.SelectionColor = Color.White


        editorBox.DeselectAll()

        For Each oneWord As String In syntax

            Dim pos As Integer = 0

            Do While editorBox.Text.ToUpper.IndexOf(oneWord.ToUpper, pos) >= 0

                pos = editorBox.Text.ToUpper.IndexOf(oneWord.ToUpper, pos)

                editorBox.Select(pos, oneWord.Length)

                editorBox.SelectionColor = Color.DodgerBlue
                editorBox.SelectionFont = New Font(editorBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold)



                pos += 1

            Loop

        Next

        editorBox.SelectionStart = selectStart

        editorBox.SelectionLength = 0

    End If
```

I've read through this, and I understand most of it. However, as of now, it selects the entire text box and highlights it, searching through and coloring all the words again. After even 50 lines, it gets really bad and laggy. I figured if I just select the current line only, it won't be laggy at all. I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
editorBox.Select(editorBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine, editorBox.Text.Length)
```

Even if I hit 'space', it still highlights all of the textbox. Is there anything else I could do to make it select just the current line and highlight it?

Comment: You seem to have put some effort in this, but I must still recommend you to use something that's built specifically for syntax highlighting. Using `Select`, `SelectionStart`/`-Length` etc. gets laggy due to that the control actually draws the selection even though fast enough that you might not see it.

Comment: I tried to make my own syntax highlighting too one time, at the end I found out about ScintillaNET, which is a control for the .NET languages based on the native Scintilla control. It does syntax highlighting perfectly without any lag or memory eating. [ScintillaNET 2.6](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) - [ScintillaNET 3.x](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).

Comment: Am I able to create custom keywords to be highlighted? Anyways, thanks for the suggestion. I've heard of it before, but never really understood how to use it. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Yes you are. Look on how to create a custom Lexer. Scintilla is highly customizable.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the example for 2.6, but [here's how you perform basic Syntax Highlighting in 3.x](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Automatic-Syntax-Highlighting). Also, [custom Lexer](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Custom-Syntax-Highlighting).

Answer (score 0):

You need to start at the current line, which that does, but then you highlight the rest of the text in that code. Find VbNewLine from GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine and use that.

Comment: Is it at editorBox.select(pos...) since pos is 0? If so, would I just replace pos with the currentline? Thanks

Comment: Start position is fine, you select the rest of the text by using text.length.